# ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 on Gitlab CI

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, sequelize.js, gitlab-ci

I am currently working on a project, and i have a big problem about CI with Gitlab. There is two container build with `docker-compose`, one is an API and the other one is PostgreSQL database.

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml :

```yaml
image: node:lastest

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: test
  POSTGRES_USER: user
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
  POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
  POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
  POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
  NODE_ENV: test

services:
  - postgres:12.2-alpine


stages:
   - test

eslint:
  stage: test
  image: node:12.18.2-alpine3.9
  before_script:
    - npm install
  script:
    - npm run linter
  except:
    - develop

audit:
  stage: test
  image: node:12.18.2-alpine3.9
  before_script:
    - npm install
    - npm install -g sequelize-cli
    - npx sequelize-cli db:create
  script:
    - npm test
  allow_failure: false
  except:
    - develop
```

So, i got this error :

```sh
$ npx sequelize-cli db:create
Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.18.2, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.3.5]
Loaded configuration file "config/database.js".
Using environment "development".
ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What am I missing?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't know gitlab CI but I suppose you must setup correctly the IP or Name of the container containing the PostgreSQL server instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem should be in your `config/database.js` file.

Check if the host in this file is `postgres` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thank you ! I just replaced my `DATABASE_IP` environment variable on the gitlab-ci file with the value `postgres`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your npm command does not use the POSTGRES_HOST in variables section. Instead it uses 127.0.0.1 when connecting to postgres and fails because your service is not running locally. Fix that and it should be available at `postgres`.